# Trouble Writing an If-else conditional for a loop in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to write an if else conditional that displays one post if its from a catergory called home, but displays the default one if its not.

I'm not sure what syntax wordpress use's for this exactly to output either a post from the category or display the post from the default category.

If someone can give me some guidance I would be very greatful.

Here is what I've got so far, I'm not sure what I need to output in the if and else excute brackets.

Currently, I've got the latest posts from the individual post types to display and need to add a bit that basically overrides that if a post is in category home is selected.

```
<?php
$query = new WP_Query('post_type=testimonial&catergory_name=home&showposts=1&paged=' . $paged);
$postcount = 0;
?>

<?php if ($query->have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>
<?php $postcount++; ?>
<li> 
<A HREF="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"></A>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">

//start of my ifelse conditional
<?php if (catergory_name=home == true) {

} else { }

<?php
if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
// check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
the_post_thumbnail('thumb-casestudy');
}else {
?>

<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/assets/images/default.jpg" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"/>
<?php } ?>
 </a>

<h4><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>

<p class="hm_text"><?php 
//the_excerpt(); 
echo get_post_meta($query->post->ID, 'wpld_cf_home_page_text', true) 
?></p>




</li>
 <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else : ?>
<?php endif; ?>
            <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: Eww. Can you please format your code so that's tabbed correctly, so it's actually readable? And point out the bits you're working on - there's a fair bit of code to dig through there.

Comment: I've tried editting it the best I can, I've added a comment on the loop I've started.

Comment: "//start of my ifelse conditional" is what it reads

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably because you have no closing php tag after your else condition, yet you start another opening php tag.

```
//start of my ifelse conditional
<?php if (catergory_name=home == true) {

} else { }
?> <---- NEED TO CLOSE THIS CLAUSE
<?php
if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
// check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
the_post_thumbnail('thumb-casestudy');
}else {
?>
```